# I can't add a new element to dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

There is something wrong with the expand() method.

```
#include <iostream> 

struct obj
{
    int fInt;
    float fFloat;
};

template <typename T>

class dynamicArray {
private:
    T* myArray;
    int elements;
    int size;

public:
    dynamicArray();
    void add(T dane);
    void expand();
    void init(int el);
    T get(int index);
};

template <typename T>
dynamicArray<T>::dynamicArray()
{
    this->size = 1;
    this->elements = 0;
    this->myArray = new T[this->size];
    init(this->elements);
}

template <typename T>
T dynamicArray<T>::get(int index)
{
    return this->myArray[index];
}

template <typename T>
void dynamicArray<T>::init(int el)
{
    for (size_t i = el; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        this->myArray[this->elements] = nullptr;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void dynamicArray<T>::expand()
{
    this->size *= 2;
    T* tempArr = new T[this->size];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = this->myArray[i];
        //tempArr[i] = new T(*this->myArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)
    {
        delete this->myArray[i];
    }
    delete this->myArray;
    this->myArray = tempArr;
    init(this->elements);
}

template <typename T>
void dynamicArray<T>::add(T dane)
{
    if (this->size == this->elements)
        this->expand();

    this->myArray[this->elements] = dane;
    this->elements++;
}

int main()
{
    dynamicArray<obj*>* arr = new dynamicArray<obj*>();
    obj* so = new obj;
    so->fInt = 2;
    so->fFloat = 2;
    arr->add(so);
    obj* so2 = new obj;
    so2->fInt = 3;
    so2->fFloat = 3;
    arr->add(so2);
    so = arr->get(0);
    so2 = arr->get(1);
    std::cout << so->fInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << so->fInt;

}
```

In this for loop I would like to assign to temporary array elements of myArray but they are not the copies

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = this->myArray[i];
        //tempArr[i] = new T(*this->myArray[i]);
    }
```

and when I delete them they disappear from tempArr too.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)
    {
        delete this->myArray[i];
    }
```

I tried couple things but I can't find the solution.

```
tempArr[i] = new T(*this->myArray[i]);
```

I am not sure if this is the right track, but it's giving me a

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'obj' to 'T'

and

> '=' cannot convert from 'T*' to 'T'

Comment: Are you doing this for homework? Otherwise use `std::vector`, and forget that `new` exists

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)   {  delete this->myArray[i];  }` is undefined behavior  for memory allocated with `this->myArray = new T[this->size];` You can't mix new[] and delete. new[] goes with delete[] and new goes with delete. The loop should have been replaced with `delete [] myArray;`

Comment: `expand()` `delete`s individual members of the array. But there's nothing in the shown code that `new`s them, only the array itself. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: `init` is repeatedly assigning to the same value (and the values are already null pointers)

Comment: And if you're doing homework ask your teacher to tell you about std::vector after you've finished the assignment. Because that is what everyone in your class should use in the future. new/delete should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: If you are using `g++` or `clang++` add these options: `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`. It'll actually tell you about the `alloc-dealloc-mismatch (operator new [] vs operator delete)` problem @drescherjm mentioned when you run the program.

Comment: A dynamic array in C++ is spelled `std::vector` in all but the rarest cases.

Comment: It's my homework. I fricking hate and don't understand pointers. I was doing this with tutorial that was ** that's why the code is big mess.

Comment: @xzysiek One important (and simple) thing to remember: For every `new` there should be exactly one `delete`. For every `new[]` there should be exactly one `delete[]`. Your `new T[this->size]` is a `new[]`, so it should have exactly one `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got yourself confused, you have a pointer to an array of `T`, not a pointer to an array of `T*`, but some of your code is written as if you had the latter.

This (in `expand`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->elements; i++)
{
    delete this->myArray[i];
}
delete this->myArray;
```

should simply be

```
delete[] this->myArray;
```

You can't delete individual array elements because they are not (necessarily) pointers. And `delete[] this->myArray;` will invoke the destructor for all elements in your array.

And `init` can simply be deleted, because again it assumes that your array elements are pointers.

Try writing some code with `dynamicArray<int>`, so that your `T` is definitely not a pointer. That will find all the places where you've incorrectly assumed that `T` is a pointer (in case I've missed any).